# Rails - Create form fields dynamically and save them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm building an ad-system where users can dynamically create 'fields' for each ad type.

---

My models and example values:

```
AdType:  
| id | name  
|----|-----  
| 1  | Hotel  
| 2  | Apartment  

AdOption:  
| id | ad_type_id | name  
|----|------------|-----
| 1  | 1          | Star rating  
| 2  | 1          | Breakfast included?  
| 3  | 2          | Number of rooms  

AdValue: (Example after saving)  
| id | ad_id | ad_option_id  | value  
|----|-------|---------------|------  
| 1  | 1     | 1 (stars)     | 5  
| 2  | 1     | 2 (breakfast) | true  

Ad: (Example after saving)  
| id | description     | etc....  
|----|-----------------|--------  
| 1  | very nice hotel | .......
```

---

So let's say I want to create a new ad, and I choose Hotel as the ad type.
Then I need my view to dynamically create fields like this: (I'm guessing?)

```
[Label] Star rating:  
[hidden_field :ad_id] [hidden_field :ad_option_id] [text_field :value]  

[Label] Breakfast included?  
[hidden_field :ad_id] [hidden_field :ad_option_id] [text_field :value]
```

And also, how to save the values when the ad record is saved

---

I hope this is understandable. If not just ask and I'll try to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the initial field in your form (AdType), then use javascript event listeners to check which option has been selected, and populate the field with the appropriate html.

jQuery probably has plugins that would do this for you, but coding it in plain JavaScript shouldn't be too difficult.